# Can't recognize steps from custom Context

Tags: php, behat

I've setup my first Behat project, but I'm having troubles defining contexts other than FeatureContext. It gets created (I checked with a die in __construct), but the steps don't get called.

Here my folder structure:

```
|-root
  |-bin
  |-features
    |-FeatureContext.php
    |-PageLoaderContext.php
    |-page_loading.feature
```

My package.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "behat/behat":           "3.0.5",
    "behat/mink-extension":  "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver":     "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver":  "*",
    "behat/mink-zombie-driver":  "*",
    "symfony/http-kernel":  "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  } 
}
```

Here's my behat.yaml

```
default:            
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - PageLoaderContext
```

And my feature

```
Feature: Tutte le pagine del sito caricano senza errori
  Per poter usare il sito
  Come utente
  Ho bisogno che tutte le pagine carichino senza errori

  Scenario Outline: Controlla il caricamento senza errori di pagine significative
    Given I'm on "<url>"
    When La pagina finisce di caricare
    Then Dovrei ottenere uno status code HTTP pari a "<code>"
    And Il "<selector>" della pagina dovrebbe contenere "<value>"

    Examples:
        | url | code | selector   | value  |
        | ?   | 200  | head title | Spagro |
```

PageLoaderContext.php

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;

class PageLoaderContext implements \Behat\Behat\Context\Context
{
  /**
   * @Given /^Carico la pagina "([^"]*)"$/
   */
  public function caricoLaPagina($arg1)
  {
    throw new PendingException();
  }

  /**
   * @When /^La pagina finisce di caricare$/
   */
  public function laPaginaFinisceDiCaricare()
  {
    throw new PendingException();
  }

  /**
   * @Then /^Dovrei ottenere uno status code HTTP pari a "([^"]*)"$/
   */
  public function dovreiOttenereUnoStatusCodeHttpPariA($arg1)
  {
    throw new PendingException();
  }

  /**
   * @Given /^Il "([^"]*)" della pagina dovrebbe contenere "([^"]*)"$/
   */
  public function ilDellaPaginaDovrebbeContenere($arg1, $arg2)
  {
    throw new PendingException();
  }
}
```

Like I said, if I implement the steps in FeatureContext, all is fine, but this won't work.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `behat.yml` to

```
default:            
  suites:
    pageLoaderSuite:
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/features
      contexts:
        - Path\To\Your\Context
```

However I can see that you don't have namespaced `PageLoaderContextClass`

Answer (score 0):

I tried making suites work, but Behat seems to ignore them. So I had to use profiles in place on suites and it worked.

```
*behat.yaml*
page_loading:
  paths:
    features:  features\bootstrap\page_loading
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%
  context:
    class: PageLoaderContext
```

Now, for each feature, I create a folder in bootstrap with the .feature files and the context class.